# Android - setting X,Y of image programmatically

Tags: android

I have two ImageViews inside an AbsoluteLayout.

```
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/whitebackground" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/floorPlanBackgroundImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_lights_gray"
    android:scaleType="center" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/fpLight"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_lights_gray"
    android:scaleType="center" android:layout_x="50px" android:layout_y="50px" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

the floorPlanBackgroundImage is dynamically set from an image that is 800x600 in size. The can scroll around it.

My second image, fpLight represents a light in a room. It's a small 20x20 image. What I need to do is change the layout_x & layout_y properties in code, but I don't see a way to set that in the ImageView.

I'd expected something like this...

fpLight.setLayoutX("55px");

Is there a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams param = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y)
```

layout Parameter object with the preferred x and y and set it to your fpLight image by

```
fpLight.setLayoutParams(param);
```

**AbsoluteLayout is Deprecated**

You should use `RelativeLayout` instead

**EXAMPLE:**

Suppose you want a ImageView of size 50x60 on your screen at postion (70x80)

```
// RelativeLayout. though you can use xml RelativeLayout here too by `findViewById()`
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
// ImageView
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

// Setting layout params to our RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 60);

// Setting position of our ImageView
layoutParams.leftMargin = 70;
layoutParams.topMargin = 80;

// Finally Adding the imageView to RelativeLayout and its position
relativeLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 10):

```
yourImageView.setX(floatXcoord);
yourImageView.setY(floatYcoord);
```

Comment: simple and straightforward code that makes perfect sense, and works, for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

**JAVA CODE**

imgPositionX  --> Your X
imgPositionY  --> Your Y

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
this.screenWidth = (float) displayMetrics.widthPixels;
this.screenHeight = (float) (displayMetrics.heightPixels - ImageUtils.dpToPx(this, 105.0f));

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
float height = screenHeight;
float width = screenWidth;
float imageTopwidth = imgPositionY * width;
float imageTop = imageTopwidth / 300;
float imageleftwidth = width * imgPositionX;
float imageLeft = imageleftwidth / 300;

params.topMargin = (int) imageTop;
params.leftMargin = (int) imageLeft;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**XML CODE**

```
 <FrameLayout
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5dp"
           android:id="@+id/greeting_btn"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:visibility="gone">

<ImageView
          android:id="@+id/select_img"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_select_image"
          app:tint="@color/app_color" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Here is ImageUtils Claas**

```
 public class ImageUtils {
    public static int dpToPx(Context context, float f) {
        context.getResources();
        return (int) (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density * f);
    }
}
```