# How to draw a button on specific location in Android?

Tags: android

I want to draw a button in an android application at a specific point say (x,y), the point will be generated at runtime.
So how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use `AbsoluteLayout` which can help you in setting the exact position of the view by the property of the view `android:layout_x` and `android:layout_y`

**UPDATE**

To add x, y on Runtime check these,

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418726/android-setting-x-y-of-image-programmatically)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441475/android-change-absolute-position-of-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: FYI, AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.

Comment: So, let me know what is the harm in using a deprecated layout.

Answer (score 0):

For that use below code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in this code just Add `android:layout_margin`
by using margin u can set your button as per your requirement.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LinearLayout:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linParams = 
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
linParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
button.setLayoutParams(linParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout) layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your code:

```
int posX = 10, posY = 20;
Button b = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(posX, posY, 0, 0);
b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: You are using a RelativeLayout in xml and treating it as a LinearLayout in code, will that work?