# How to change the image's coordinates by using java

Tags: java, android

Goal:
When click on the button, I would like to change the picture's X and Y coordinate to 
android:layout_x 35dp android:layout_y: 541dp by using java code and not XML code.

Questions:
I cannot find the correct syntax code in order do it.

Do you know how to do it?

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm newbie in android

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="158dp"
        android:layout_y="77dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="testtest"
        android:text="Button" />



</AbsoluteLayout>
```

---

```
package com.jfdimarzio.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        myImageView .setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
    }

    public void testtest(View view)
    {
        AbsoluteLayout relativeLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        myImageView.layout(10,10,10,10);
        //myImageView.layout(3,3,3,3);


    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - setting X,Y of image programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418726/android-setting-x-y-of-image-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't seen `AbsoluteLayout` for years o.o

In Android, a View's location isn't actually specified by either the `View` itself or the `ViewGroup` that contains the View. Instead, it's specified by the `LayoutParams` that accompanies the View.

In your xml file, when creating your View, the **width**, **height**, **margins**, and the **x** and **y** values are all within a `LayoutParams` object that is automatically created and set onto the View.

The `LayoutParams` is the component that tells the container how it should position the View.

So if you want to update the **x** and **y** of your `ImageView`, you'll need to edit from it's `LayoutParams`.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) myImageView.getLayoutParams();
params.x = NEW_X_VALUE; //Please enter this yourself
params.y = NEW_Y_VALUE; //Be careful of DP to PX conversions
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
myImageView.requestLayout();
```

So what I'm doing here is fetching the `LayoutParams` that was created through the xml and changing the x and y values within it. Afterwards, I set the modified LayoutParams back into the ImageView.

I believe `setLayoutParams()` is already enough to cause the parent container to update the View's location, but just incase it doesn't... `requestLayout()` should.

Comment: Thank you for your help!